# Handling Space url in json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I've url like this for the json format.

```
http://abcde.com/api.php?CMD=TRACKVEHICLE&APIKEY=1234&TERMINAL=358899052470419&GPSSTART=13-05-2016 2000:34:00&GPSEND=13-05-2016 2014:34:00
```

when i passed to url in the browser there is an extra '%' string like below

```
http://abcde.com/api.php?CMD=TRACKVEHICLE&APIKEY=1234&TERMINAL=358899052470419&GPSSTART=13-05-2016%2000:34:00&GPSEND=13-05-2016%2014:34:00
```

how to handle that % ?, how to convert to UTF-8 my script can read the json format, just like i paste on the browser.

```
public function getMapLine() {

        $superspring_url="http://abcde.com/api.php?CMD=TRACKVEHICLE&APIKEY=1234&TERMINAL=358899052470419&GPSSTART=13-05-2016 2000:34:00&GPSEND=13-05-2016 2014:34:00";

        $curl = curl_init($superspring_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //execute the session
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
        //finish off the session
        curl_close($curl);

        $decoded = json_decode($curl_response,TRUE);


        var_dump($curl_response);
    }
```

i use that above script to dump but this one is the below result because of the '%' string.

```
string(14) "Query failed! "
```

but when i try to use that % on my php script it shown the url.

Comment: You should try http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code above `$curl = curl_init($superspring_url);` :

```
$superspring_url = str_replace (' ', '%20', $superspring_url);
```